# How to add polyline in bottom half of the map view iOS 7

Tags: ios, uiview, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkpolyline

Please see below image:

[image]

As you can see, I added a `mkpolyline` to my `mkmapview` but because the route is to big so part of the route has been move behind the other subviews.

I want to make a change so that for all times, the positions of the poly-line be at bottom half of the map view(at below of the `uitable` that shows step instructions). Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to zoom the map view out in order to have the route displayed below the route text view(s). There are 2 ways to do that generally:

1. Determine the new `MKCoordinateRegion` (or `MKMapRect`), which is the bounds of your route with extra padding space above
2. Change the `MKMapView` frame such that it sits below the route text views and maintain a `region` which fits the route

Option 2 is easier, but has a different visual effect. Option 1 requires you to pad the display area while maintaining the route display area.

For option 1, use the fact that you already zoom the map to the route and manipulate the `visibleMapRect`. Try:

```
MKMapRect visibleMapRect = map.visibleMapRect;
visibleMapRect.origin.y = visibleMapRect.size.height;
visibleMapRect.size.height *= 2;
map.visibleMapRect = visibleMapRect;
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Do you have any link to any tutorials for option 1?

Comment: Not specifically for that, but added an option that should hopefully work.